# Troubles using CrossriderAPI with rails 4 turbolinks

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, crossrider

I'm having some troubles using **CrossriderAPI** with **turbolinks**, my scenario is this:

**1**. Going on my http://website.local/

**2**. running a check to see if **Crossrider** extension is ready:

`CrossriderAPI.isAppReady('xxxxx', function(r) { if (r) (console.log('ready')) })`

**3**. yes of course, is it.

**4**. Navigating through the website (using **`turbolinks`**)

**5**. well, troubles start by here. **`turbolinks`** change the DOM to each request, but when I retry to check if **Crossrider** extension is ready, and I'm investigating why, what i receive is `false`. It seems not see anymore our extension.

I'm debugging this **[code](http://w9u6a2p6.ssl.hwcdn.net/plugins/javascripts/crossriderAPI.js)** to see if I get out from this problem.

has anyone succeeded with this? Any help or advice would be great!

Antonio

Comment: just disable turbolink

Comment: @apneadiving too simple! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Turbolinks, but in general based on their GitHub readme that states that "you can't rely on DOMContentLoaded or jQuery.ready() to trigger your code", I would think that it severely impedes extensions that rely on these events as they run when the page loads.

Specifically in this instance, since Turbolinks replaces the body content, it disrupts the CrossriderAPI library that utilizes the DOM content for its operation. Hence, without considerable reworking of the code, I don't think that Turbolinks can co-exist with the CrossriderAPI and can disrupt with extension functionality.

Comment: after some magic tries, I'm arrived to the conclusion that you're totally right.